# HTACCESS Rule to NGINX Configuration File (One Rule)

Tags: nginx

I'm struggling with getting one rule that I had in my HTACCESS file, to work within my NGINX configuration files. I've used the converters online, and searched on Google but can't seem to find a solution that'll work. I feel this would be a quick solution for someone a bit more familiar with NGINX redirects. I sure hope so! :-)

HTACESS Rule:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/services/automotive-services/(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/automotive-services/$1
```

I'm trying to get my NGINX rule to do the following...

- http://www.domain.com/services/automotive-services/ should go to http://www.domain.com/automotive-services/
- http://www.domain.com/services/automotive-services/pagenamehere should go to http://www.domain.com/automotive-services/pagenamehere

Any assistance with this would be great! :-)

Answer (score 0):

You have to remember that Nginx does not do anything with htaccess files. Htaccess files are purely an Apache construct.

As for how you would do the RedirectMatch in Nginx, put this in your server configuration:

```
if ( $request_filename ~ services/.+ ) {
   rewrite ^(.*) http://www.domain.com/$1 permanent;
}
```

This will check if `$request_filename` contains "services", and if it does, it will rewrite it via 301 to `http://www.domain.com/`.